# how can i solve this question? using self inner join and some conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
the first picture is the table . second picture is the expected output.
conditions are 
 1. refids should be same. 
 2. for all the same ref ids (a.start,a.end &b.start,b.end) in the current and previous row. 
 3. should calculate the time difference which is greater than or equal to one day.

Comment: Why is the time difference expressed as a data? Shouldn't it be a number of days, hours, minutes, etc.?

Comment: @TheImpaler it s okay to be any method ! I just want to pass all the conditions

Comment: What if it is a phpmyadmin 5.7.17 database mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want pairs of rows that match certain condition. You can perform a join to identify the pairs.

You don't say which version of MySQL you are using but in MySQL 8.x you can do:

```
with
x as (
  select a.id  
  from my_table a
  join my_table b on b.id = a.id + 1
                 and b.refid = a.refid
                 and (a.detail = 'a.end' and b.detail = 'a.start'
                   or a.detail = 'b.end' and b.detail = 'b.start')
)
select t.*
from my_table t
join x on t.id = x.id or t.id = x.id + 1
```

For MySQL 5.x you can do:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
join (
  select a.id  
  from my_table a
  join my_table b on b.id = a.id + 1
                 and b.refid = a.refid
                 and (a.detail = 'a.end' and b.detail = 'a.start'
                   or a.detail = 'b.end' and b.detail = 'b.start')
) x on t.id = x.id or t.id = x.id + 1
```

Comment: am using a phpmyadmin database version 5.7.17 brother . can you change this one according to that version  ?

Comment: @V2rson Added query for MySQL 5.x